How to replace tiles in Unity?
I want to build some levels (rooms) for my game but i didn't make tile map yet. I want to build my level using placeholder images and when i make tile map i want to replace placeholders with normal tiles. But how can i replace all tiles without destroying the scene?
I tried to replace source image of tile map and each tile individually but it just destroys all tiles and forces me to draw it again. I tried to find answer on the internet but i only found two post where first one was without answer and second one didn't work for some reason. I have just noticed that i was replacing not sprites but tile assets themselves. I replaced source images of sprites and it worked! Thanks people from comments for help.

you need to show some code, cos i change tiles all the time in my game and its never failed to work

Have you tried this?

if you don't want to change scene and stay in one scene you can save you'r maps as prefab and save them to an public array and everytime you want to change your level you can load next level with instantiate function
but Actually it not good way because you need to change player position, enemy positions and every object you have and it will be long work and script to write :)
and if you have large prefab your frame rate will drop for a second (you can fix it with simple loading system )
